# Set the background color of my buttons excluding accessory buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to globally change the color of my buttons, but I'm struggling with one in particular. I have a UITableView which in its cells I put an UITableViewCellAccessory. This is contained in a UIViewController and below this I have a UIStackView with a button inside, this is the one I want to change the background color.

I've trying

```objectivec
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyClass class], nil] setBackground:myColor];
```

But **the problem is that it also paints the accessory**

Also something like

```objectivec
[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[MyClass class], [UIViewController class], [UIStackView class]]] setBackground:myColor];
```

this one does nothing

Is there anything else I can try to achieve this?

Comment: Your `whenContainedInInstancesOf` needs to be arranged from inner to outer. It is unlikely that your view controller is inside the stack view.

Comment: @matt Something like this? [UIButton appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIStackView class], [UIViewController class], [MyClass class]]] setBackground:myColor];

Comment: Yep, that works, thank you! I had been struggling all day with that, I feel like when you miss a semicolon haha